# CronJob require absolute path

Tags: php, path, cron, require, jobs

I'm using CronJob the following way to trigger a php script:

```
/web/cgi-bin/php5 $HOME/html/library/myScript.php auth_key=xxxxxxx
```

But I experience problems with require and I tried everything I could find on stackO already.
It seems it can't load the SendGrid autoloader

```
//myScript.php
#!/web/cgi-bin/php5
<?php
include('../config.php'); // this works well for some reason...

if(isset($_GET['auth_key']) && $_GET['auth_key'] == "xxxxxxx")
{
    // send email
    include('home/content/aa/bbbbbb/html/scripts/sendgrid/lib/SendGrid.php'); // this works only this way
    include('home/content/aa/bbbbbb/html/scripts/unirest/lib/Unirest.php'); // this too

    SendGrid::register_autoloader(); // fails here!
}
?>
```

And this did not work either:

```
set_include_path('/home/content/aa/bbbbbb/html/');
require 'scripts/sendgrid/lib/SendGrid.php';
require 'scripts/unirest/lib/Unirest.php';
```

And neither did this:

```
chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
```

The SendGrid.php is the folowwin, and I reckon the problem lies in there somewhere since this makes also require calls!

```
//SendGrid.php
<?php
class SendGrid {
const VERSION = "1.1.5";

protected $namespace = "SendGrid",
        $username,
        $password,
        $web,
        $smtp;

public function __construct($username, $password) {
    $this->username = $username;
    $this->password = $password;
}

public static function register_autoloader() {
    spl_autoload_register(array('SendGrid', 'autoloader'));
}

public static function autoloader($class) {
// Check that the class starts with "SendGrid"
if ($class == 'SendGrid' || stripos($class, 'SendGrid\\') === 0) {
    $file = str_replace('\\', '/', $class);

    if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . $file . '.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . $file . '.php');
    }
}
}

public function __get($api) {
$name = $api;

if($this->$name != null) {
  return $this->$name;
}

$api = $this->namespace . "\\" . ucwords($api);
$class_name = str_replace('\\', '/', "$api.php");
$file = __dir__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $class_name;

if (!file_exists($file)) {
  throw new Exception("Api '$class_name' not found.");
}
require_once $file;

$this->$name = new $api($this->username, $this->password);
return $this->$name;
}
}
```

Any help is much appreciated of course!
Thanks in advance, Lois

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, Cron did not fulfill the job (no pun intended).

I'm using this from now on and it seems to do the work just perfectly: http://atrigger.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the the libs

```
require 'scripts/sendgrid/lib/SendGrid.php';
require 'scripts/unirest/lib/Unirest.php';
```

I suggest you use fully qualified paths to the files - otherwise you will need to set the include path to get them into scope

```
set_include_path('path/to/scripts/directory');
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your reply! Well I tried to include the libs and it works only when I do it this way I describe in my post

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
__DIR__
```

magic constant with require_once.

The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned. This is equivalent to dirname(**FILE**). This directory name does not have a trailing slash unless it is the root directory. (Added in PHP 5.3.0.)

```
require_once(realpath(__DIR__ . "/../config.php"));
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for your time. I tried this solution but did not work. I'm lost really :-/ it's odd..

Comment: Yes, just now. it works and returns the correct one I have been using, meaning: "/home/content/aa/bbbbbb/html/library" which is where my php script is played from. now the question is how do I trick the SendGrid loader which uses these paths inside: require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . $file . '.php'); and also $file = __dir__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $class_name; (check in my post above)

Comment: never mind, i'm using this from now on: http://atrigger.com/ and it seems to work!